# How to extract lines with multiple patterns in Linux?

Tags: linux

my command:

```
awk '/"California"/ && / "Crude Prevalences"/{print}' U.S._Chronic_Disease_Indicators__CDI_.csv | less
```

In Linux, I want to extract lines with both "California" and "Crude Prevalences", but when I less out, it only shows "~". Is there anything wrong with my command? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a couple of ways to do it..

awk

```
awk '/"California"/ && /"Crude Prevalences"/' U.S._Chronic_Disease_Indicators__CDI_.csv | less
```

grep

```
grep '"California"' U.S._Chronic_Disease_Indicators__CDI_.csv | grep '"Crude Prevalences"' | less
```

Comment: Thank you! but the answer is required to use awk.

Comment: The first example uses awk.